# How to get custom data from Parse without issues

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

If you look here https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJGW2.jpg you can see my issue.

```
if PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("receivedItems") != nil && PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("sentItems") != nil {

        PFUser.currentUser()!.addObject(receivedItemsArr, forKey: "receivedItems")
        PFUser.currentUser()!.addObject(sentItemsArr, forKey: "sentItems")

    } else {

        var qry = PFQuery()

        receivedItemsArr = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("receivedItems") as! [GroceryItem]
        sentItemsArr = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("sentItems") as! [GroceryItem]

    }
```

I want to make a custom array object if it doesn't exist yet, but when I try to access it in the `else` statement , it gives me this error

```
Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and crashes the app . Do I have to use a PFQuery? I don't know how to! could you help with code that would help with the error in the else statement and possibly fix it?

Comment: You should post as code, not an image file. You're apt to get more responses, as the question will be easier to read.

Comment: do you think this is better?

Comment: what are trying to do/

Comment: get the array from parse

Comment: I haven't used Parse, but the warning you're getting re: a long-running operation on the main thread caught my attention. For that aspect of your question, here's a good explanation of performing long-running commands off the main thread from Paul Hegarty. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjMP15rE6r0#t=50m34s

Comment: ah thanks ill look at it but i kinda want some code help

Comment: Have you inserted a breakpoint to figure out what your `nil` value is?

Comment: no, thats a good point ill try

Comment: guys i fixed it with logic

Comment: the problem was i != should have been ==, if it is = make new item, else get the value, they were both nil

Comment: Put your answer down below and in a day or so, it'll let you put a green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this specific question, it was a logic problem. i had to swithc it from != to == for it to make sense